# PHP 5.6.16 Not Reading $_post data

Tags: php, post

I'm using this exact version on two servers - one works flawlessly (older PHP) and this one doesn't read the `$_POST` data of a `checkbox` element.

The Form:

```
<form method=post action=fish.php?livewell=1&processrelease=1 enctype="multipart/form-data">Array ( )
    <table border=1 width=800>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <CENTER>Fish</td>
            <td>
                <CENTER>Value</td>
            <tD>
                <CENTER>Release</td>
            <td>
                <CENTER>League</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <CENTER>
                    <IMG SRC=pics/fish/brook_trout.jpg width=45 title="Brook Trout">
            </td>
            <td>
                <FONT COLOR=green>Brook Trout</font> (
                <A HREF=fish.php?guide=1><FONT COLOR=#666666>Regular</font></A>)(
                <B>Fish level 9</B>)
                <BR>
                <FONT COLOR=blue><B>10 inches</B></font>-
                <FONT COLOR=purple><B>1 cm</B></font>-
                <FONT COLOR=green><B>3.24 mm</B></font>[
                <FONT COLOR=brown><B>1.065 lbs</B></font>]
                <BR>
            </td>
            <td>
                <CENTER>
                    <FONT COLOR=green>$0.90</font>
                    <BR>
            </td>
            <td>
                <CENTER>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="55" name="lwid[]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <CENTER>
                    <IMG SRC=bigbertha.gif height=22> This defeats your previous league record for
                    <FONT COLOR=green>Brook Trout</font> of lbs.
                    <BR>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <BR>Running total right now is
    <FONT COLOR=green>$0.9</font>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <input type=submit value="Release Checked Fish">
</form>
```

But when I receive a post - all data inside `$lw[]` is blank.

Post receiving code is below :

```
$box = $_POST['lwid'];
while (list($key, $val) = @each($lwid)) {
    $livewellsel = mysql_query("select * from tblFishCapture where id='$val' and playerId=$stat[id] limit 1");
    $lwnum = mysql_num_rows($livewellsel);
    if ($lwnum > 0) {
        $lw = mysql_fetch_array($livewellsel);
        $tfishsel = mysql_query("select name from tblFishTemplates where id='$lw[fishId]' limit 1");
        $tfish = mysql_fetch_array($tfishsel);
        $label = check_fish_bonus($lw[fishId], $lw[fishSize], 1);
        $fbonus = check_fish_bonus($lw[fishId], $lw[fishSize], 0);
        $level = get_fish_level($fbonus);
        $myval = check_fish_bonus($lw[fishId], $lw[fishSize], 3);
        $pn = get_place_name($body[id]);
        $ttText = translate_text_googleapi("You release", $languageCode[languageCode]);
        $tfish[name] = translate_text_googleapi("$tfish[name]", $languageCode[languageCode]);
        $label = translate_text_googleapi("$label", $languageCode[languageCode]);
        $ttFishlevel = translate_text_googleapi("Fish level", $languageCode[languageCode]);
        $ttBIW = translate_text_googleapi("back into <FONT COLOR=blue>the water</font>", $languageCode[languageCode]);
        print "$ttText <FONT COLOR=green>$tfish[name]</font> ($label)(<B>$ttFishlevel $level</B>) $ttBIW.<BR>";
        mysql_query("delete from tblFishCapture where playerId=$stat[id] and id='$val' limit 1");
    }
}
```

When I do `print_r($_post)` it reads
`Array ( [lwid] => )`

I am using this workaround that makes my programming compatible with new PHP also :

```
if (!isset($PXM_REG_GLOB)) {

    $PXM_REG_GLOB = 1;

    if (!ini_get('register_globals')) {
        foreach(array_merge($_GET, $_POST) as $key => $val) {
            global $$key;
            $$key = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $val : addslashes($val);
        }
    }
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $val) $_POST[$key] = addslashes($val);
        foreach($_GET as $key => $val) $_GET[$key] = addslashes($val);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Is there something I'm missing in a configuration or something that isn't compatible with new PHP?

Edit :

Using

```
Using "$_POST['lwid'];
     foreach($_POST['lwid'] as $val) {
// do something
}
```

Still returns an empty result.

Comment: stop using font, learn css

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is only used if you doing a file upload

Comment: OK I have removed the enctype="multipart/form-data" but the array is still 
empty in the $_post

Print_R being Array ( [lwid] => )

Comment: No offense @JoshuaJenks, but your code is quite a mess, no indentation, the html values aren't quoted, usage of obsolete features such as `<CENTER>`, It is really hard to read.

Comment: @UriGoren Code is not a mess anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See this note regarding `register_globals` on the [official php website](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP
>   5.4.0.

Just use `$_POST['lwid']` instead of `$lwid`

Comment: Could you explain specifically what I should change? 

Are you talking this "while (list($key, $val) = @each($lwid)) {"? 

My print_r($_POST) still displays Array ( [lwid] => )

Comment: `$lwid` is not defined, so you get an error that you ignore with `@`. use `$_POST['lwid']` instead of `$lwid`

Comment: With "while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($_POST['lwid']))" I still have no results and the array is empty. Are you talking about modifying something in the HTML form?

Comment: Are you saying I need to change " <input type="checkbox" value="55" name="lwid[]">?

Comment: Using "$_POST['lwid'];
     foreach($_POST['lwid'] as $val) {
// do something
}

Still returns empty array

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it myself.

Changed the checkbox to

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$lw[id]\" name=\"$lw[id]\">
```

And read the checkboxes with :

```
foreach ($_POST as &$val) {
//do something
}
```